# the_ID & wp_get_attachment_image_src(the_ID(), "medium") blank

Tags: post-thumbnails

Using:

```
$my_query->the_post();
$thumbnail_arr = wp_get_attachment_image_src(the_ID(), "medium");
$thumbnail = $thumbnail_arr[0];
```

`$thumbnail` is outputting a blank value.

If I echo `the_ID()` it is blank also.

Help appreciated.

**EDIT**

I've tried:

```
$my_query->the_post();
$thumbnail_arr = wp_get_attachment_image_src($my_query->post->ID, "medium");
$thumbnail = $thumbnail_arr[0];
```

but `$thumbnail` is still empty.

Comment: I know you already found a solution (to get the featured image ID/URL), but keep in mind that `the_ID()` displays the post ID, and returns nothing. So you should use `get_the_ID()` instead to get the post ID. That way, `echo get_the_ID()` would echo the correct post ID, when inside of The Loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to:

```
 $attch_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $my_query->post->ID );
 $thumbnail_arr = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attch_id, "medium");
 $thumbnail = $thumbnail_arr[0];
```

and `$thumbnail` is returning what I want now.